# How do I remove saturated pixels from an image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pixel, astropy

My goal with the code is to print an image where I have removed all the saturated pixels (the pixels that gives off their maximum value). This is because I am analyzing data from an .fit image of a star.

The instruction I got was:
"What you need to do is figure out what the maximum pixel value is in the 2d array from the data. Then write code that will remove those values, while still keeping the image. Basically, what I want to see is a star with a hole in the middle, where you have removed the saturated pixels."

I have succeeded to find the maximum pixel value (65535) and now I need to print my image without the pixels with that particular value.

This is my code so far but now I do not know how to remove the pixels from my image.

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fits_image_filename = "Acturus_V_2s.fit"
hdul = fits.open(fits_image_filename)

data = hdul[0].data

datacut = data[610:710,755:855]
plt.imshow(datacut, origin="lower")

MaxPixelValue = np.amax(datacut)
print(MaxPixelValue)
```

And this gives the output:
65535 and my image

How am I supposed to remove those pixels?

Comment: You can't remove arbitrary pixels from an image. You can only give them a different color.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "remove pixels".   Does that mean you want to set the value of the saturated pixels to 0?   A better choice might be to set them to the average of the surrounding non-saturated pixels.   I don't see how you could literally remove the pixels, since images don't usually have "holes" in them.

Comment: Find and cure [hotpixels](https://www.astropy.org/ccd-reduction-and-photometry-guide/v/dev/notebooks/08-01-Identifying-hot-pixels.html#some-pixels-are-too-hot) in astropy documentation

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have pointed out, it's not generally possible to "remove" pixels from an image. But there are a few ways of dealing with some pixels in an image while leaving the others alone. In general, to do this you'll end up creating a boolean mask -- an array with the same shape as your image but containing values that are either `True` or `False`.

```
mask = datacut >= MaxPixelValue
```

Now the `mask` array contains `True` wherever the original image is saturated and `False` everywhere else.

You can set the values of the saturated pixels to NaN, which Matplotlib will handle as blank pixels (i.e., they do not have any color when using `imshow()`).

```
datacut[mask] = np.nan
```

Alternatively, you can set the saturated pixels in your image to some indicative color (e.g. white or black):

```
datacut[mask] = 0
```

Or you can create a numpy `maskedarray`, which is a sort of combination of your original image and the mask:

```
masked_image = np.ma.masked_array(datacut, mask)
```

The numpy documentation has a brief description of how to use masked arrays.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html

I also found some documentation from the astrophysics community that might be useful, since you're also using `fits` and `astropy`.
https://prancer.physics.louisville.edu/astrowiki/index.php/Image_processing_with_Python_and_SciPy#Masked_Image_Operations